# Batch export AI and EPS files into a PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, batch-processing, eps

I have about ~600 files in .ai and .eps formats and need to export them to a .png (Full image, not layer by layer). Is there any way to do this automatically? Also it will be good if the .png file name is the same or similar to Adobe Illustrator file.

Comment: Hi Oleg, welcome to GD.SE! You can do this with a script, I would check out the official Adobe Illustrator forum which has a couple of methods for this - [Batch Export as PNG](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/318536?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Use Adobe Bridge, will export into .jpg

Answer (score 2):

I've used media encoder to change a batch of .ai files to .png. You can add the .ai files to the queue. I set up a pre-set with the following settings...
Format: PNG
Keep Export Video checked but uncheck Export as Sequence. Match Source for the other settings.
Then add the .ai files to the Media Encoder queue and run the queue.
It does seem a little slow at running the process but at least it's automated - saved me having to manually save as 1170 .ai files!

Comment: I'm new to the subject and would like to know where to find the "media enconder". It would be wonderful if you could show some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of follow up of Bettina Frankham.

I tried the Media Encoder option and it worked like a charm (Thanks!!!).

Just wanted to add, since it might not be super intuitive, after you create the preset following the instructions by Bettina, you need to change the "Format" drop down in the queue to PNG, so it will display your newly created preset in the "Preset" drop down. Other than that, the rest is flawless :)

Only for reference (since this answer might not stick together with Bettina's):

> Blockquote
> I've used media encoder to change a batch of .ai files to .png. You can add the .ai files to the queue. I set up a pre-set with the following settings... Format: PNG Keep Export Video checked but uncheck Export as Sequence. Match Source for the other settings. Then add the .ai files to the Media Encoder queue and run the queue.
> Blockquote